# Having trouble concatenating first name and last name

Tags: c

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char firstName[10];
    char lastName[10];
    char fullName[30];
    int length, length2;
    printf("Please enter the first name: ");
    scanf("%s", firstName);
    length = strlen(firstName);
    while (length > 10)
    {
        printf("Error! First name should have < 10 characters.\n");
        printf("Please enter the first name again: ");
        scanf("%s", firstName);
        length = strlen(firstName);
    }
    printf("Please enter the last name: ");
    scanf("%s", lastName);
    length2 = strlen(lastName);
    while (length2 > 10)
    {
        printf("Error! Last name should have < 10 characters.\n");
        printf("Please enter the last name again: ");
        scanf("%s", lastName);
        length2 = strlen(lastName);
    }
    strcpy(fullName, firstName);
    strcat(fullName, " ");
    strcat(fullName, lastName);
    printf("The full name is: %s\n", fullName);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to protect the user input from entering names longer than the capacity of the character arrays but having half of the last name copy onto the first name

Comment: `scanf("%9s", firstName);` - `firstName` can never hold more than `9 + 1` chars so `while(length > 10)` is impossible without *Undefined Behavior*... (the same applies to `lastName`) So what is the lesson? *Never Skimp on Buffer Size!* and protect your array bounds at the point of filling (not after -- it's too late then).

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy()` and `strcat()` are not length-safe.  One should use `strncpy()` and `strncat()`.  But if the buffer is not long enough, both these functions do not NULL terminate.

An easy solution for your case is to use `snprintf()` which will always NULL terminate:

```
size_t bytes_needed = snprintf( fullName, sizeof( fullName ), "%s %s", firstName, lastName );
if ( bytes_needed >= sizeof( fullName ) )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "<fullName> is too small, needed %lu bytes\n", bytes_needed );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic to me seems fine but there should be if condition instead of while loop.

Comment: Why should there be an `if` instead of a `while`?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using fixed size arrays in C, like `fullName`, and reading information into the array, you must put on your accountants hat and ensure you write no more characters to the array than it can hold (less `1` character for the *nul-terminating* character if you intend to use the character array as a string)

As mentioned in my first comment, when using the `scanf` family, you must use the *field-width* modifier to ensure `scanf` reads no more than `size - 1` characters to preserve room for the *nul-terminating* character. Otherwise, `scanf` will happily write outside the bounds of your array invoking *Undefined Behavior* (meaning defined execution of your code is over at that point and your code could appear to work normally or *SegFault* -- or anything in between)

Which brings up the best advice anyone can give -- *Don't attempt to read lines of user input with `scanf`*. Instead use `fgets` (or POSIX `getline`) to read an entire line at a time and then parse whatever you need from the line (or if using the whole line as a string, just trim the `'\n'` from the end). That way what remains in your input buffer doesn't depend on the `scanf` *conversion specifier* used (which torments new C programmers to no end...)

When taking user input, you must always protect against the user canceling input by entering <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows) to generate a manual `EOF`. You do that by checking the return of whatever input function you are using.

If you want to ensure the user gives you valid input (or cancels), the simply place your prompt and read within a continual loop and `break;` the loop once the input has satisfied all your conditions.

When reading more than one input into the same buffer like `fullName`, it helps to keep a variable holding the `available` (or `remaining`) character count. That way instead of testing against the full buffer size for your second input, you test against the remaining characters available in the buffer to see if your `lastName` will fit (plus one additional character for the `" "` (space) between the first/last name.

To make sure the input will fit, read into a temporary buffer of sufficient size (*Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN   128u     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC  1024u     /* max line buffer size */

int main(void)
{
    char buf[MAXC];                 /* buffer to hold input */
    char fullName[MAXN];            /* 128 chars for first/last will do */
    size_t available = MAXN - 1;    /* avaliable chars in fullName */
```

Above you have a temporary buffer of `1024` chars -- which should be more than sufficient unless the user's cat goes to sleep on the keyboard. You will read into the `1024` char buffer and then test whether it will fit in the `available` characters for `fullName`. Combining that will a continual read loop you could do:

```
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input or user cancels */
        size_t length;                  /* string funcitons use size_t */
        printf ("Please enter the first name: ");
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* use fgets - validate */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
            return 0;
        }
        buf[(length = strcspn (buf, "\r\n"))] = 0;  /* trim trailing '\n' */
        if (length > available) {   /* validate length - and save length    */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: name must have < %zu characters.\n",
                    available);
        }
        else {  /* name fits - copy */
            strcpy (fullName, buf);
            available -= length;
            break;
        }
```

(**note:** there is no need for `firstName` or `lastName` as you are putting both in `fullname`. Just read with `buf` and add to `fullName` as you go)

Also note the use of `strcspn` which returns the number of characters in the string NOT contained in the exclude set `"\r\n"`. So it reads the number of characters in the string up until the first line-ending encountered -- an then overwrites the line ending with zero (same as `'\0'`) to nul-terminate at that point. You can use `strlen`, but `strcspn` can do it for you incorporating the exclude set allowing you to nul-terminate in a single command.

The read of last name is almost identical to firstname except when you go to add last name to `fullName` you need to append a `" "` before you do. The difference being:

```
        else {  /* name fits, concatenate space and lastName */
            strcat (fullName, " ");
            strcat (fullName, buf);
            available -= length + 1;
            break;
        }
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN   128u     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC  1024u     /* max line buffer size */

int main(void)
{
    char buf[MAXC];                 /* buffer to hold input */
    char fullName[MAXN];            /* 128 chars for first/last will do */
    size_t available = MAXN - 1;    /* avaliable chars in fullName */

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input or user cancels */
        size_t length;                  /* string funcitons use size_t */
        printf ("Please enter the first name: ");
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {    /* use fgets - validate */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
            return 0;
        }
        buf[(length = strcspn (buf, "\r\n"))] = 0;  /* trim trailing '\n' */
        if (length > available) {   /* validate length - and save length    */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: name must have < %zu characters.\n",
                    available);
        }
        else {  /* name fits - copy */
            strcpy (fullName, buf);
            available -= length;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (;;) {  /* ditto - above comments */
        size_t length;
        printf ("Please enter the last name : ");
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
            return 0;
        }
        buf[(length = strcspn (buf, "\r\n"))] = 0;
        if (length > available - 1) {   /* -1 to account for space */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: name must have < %zu characters.\n",
                    available - 1);
        }
        else {  /* name fits, concatenate space and lastName */
            strcat (fullName, " ");
            strcat (fullName, buf);
            available -= length + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf ("\nThe full name is: '%s'\n", fullName);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/first_last
Please enter the first name: Samuel
Please enter the last name : Clemens

The full name is: 'Samuel Clemens'
```

or the case where the user cancels input:

```
$ ./bin/first_last
Please enter the first name: (user canceled input)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.